# How to search product programatically in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, programmatically

I want to search product in custom page so how search products programmatically in custom controller ?

**Below Magento 1.x search programmatically**

```
$queryText = Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->getQueryText();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/query_collection')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setQueryFilter($queryText);
```

this type of search code available in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick reference, we can take a look:

**vendor/magento/module-search/Model/ResourceModel/Query/Collection.php**

```
public function setQueryFilter($query)
{
        ......
}
```

In Magento 1, it's **Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Query_Collection** `public function setQueryFilter($query) {......}`

And then navigate to **vendor/magento/module-search/Model/Query.php**

```
 public function getSuggestCollection()
 {
        $collection = $this->getData('suggest_collection');
        if ($collection === null) {
            $collection = $this->_queryCollectionFactory->create()->setStoreId(
                $this->getStoreId()
            )->setQueryFilter(
                $this->getQueryText()
            );
            $this->setData('suggest_collection', $collection);
        }
        return $collection;
 }
```

We can see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code its work for me:

```
$this->filterBuilder->setField('search_term');
$this->filterBuilder->setValue('wat');
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
$searchCriteria->setRequestName("quick_search_container");
$this->searchResult = $this->searchInterface->search($searchCriteria);

//Create Temp table for store result 
$temporaryStorage = $this->temporaryStorageFactory->create();
$table = $temporaryStorage->storeApiDocuments($this->searchResult->getItems());        
$productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->getSelect()->joinInner(
       ['search_result' => $table->getName()],
       'e.entity_id = search_result.' . TemporaryStorage::FIELD_ENTITY_ID,
       []
);


// Classes need to load

use Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface;  //$this->searchInterface
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\TemporaryStorageFactory; // $this->temporaryStorageFactory
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder; // $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\TemporaryStorage; //TemporaryStorage
```