# how to advanced search a products programatically

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, programmatically

I need to search a products using advanced search with custom attributes  programmatically. My advanced search works fine, i need to search product programmatically with our custom attributes.

I follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128443/how-to-search-product-programatically-in-magento-2) But magento 2 doesn't have these files   `vendor/magento/module-search/Model/ResourceModel/Query/Collection.php`

Suggest me How to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Find "Search criteria" section :)

http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/

Answer (score 0):

Think observing the vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Controller\Advanced\Result.php should give you enough hints to how Magento does it.

Here is a little article / snippet about it http://foggyline.net/magento-2-programmatically-search-product-using-advanced-search-engine/.